# Computing the probability of two variables of the same sample.

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

Problem: The mean of a variety of apple is 400g with a standard deviation of 50g. If we choose 2 random apples of this variety, what would be the probability that the first one weights 150g more than the second one?

If I write P (X1 ≥ X1’ + 150), am I on the right track?

And if the question was instead: "what is the probability that the difference in weight between the two apple is bigger than 150", is it the same thing calculation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are thinking along the correct lines for the first one:

$P(X_2>X_1+150)=\int f(x)[1-F(x+150)] dx$ since you need to consider all possible outcomes of $X_1$

Your second question is different:

$D=|X_1-X_2|\rightarrow P(D>150) = 2P(X_2>X_1+150)$ by symmetry arguments.

Comment: I'm not really that good at interpreting the integral, is it the right thing to do:= P (X1 – X2 – 150 ≥ 0)
= P (Y ≥ 0)
~ N (µ1 - µ1’ – 150; √(σ^2+σ'^2 ))? 

Thank you for clarifying!